# What is this python code doing to xml and how can i do the same on json

Tags: python, json, xml

i am trying to update old python code that edits and outputs an xml file to do the same operations on an JSON file. Mind you I am not very familiar with python. Until this point in the code, I have a json formatted file and an xml formatted file and they both contain the same information.

Below code is taking a filename as first parameter, and this thing as second parameter {'output/exp':'freefcst'} (Is this a dictionary? or tuple? or something else?)

```py
def UpdateXml(filename,config,silent=True,envartime=None):

    tree = ET.parse(filename)
    root = tree.getroot()

    for el in config.keys():
        if root.find(el) is not None:
            if silent is False: print 'Setting ', el, ' to ', config[el]
            root.find(el).text = config[el]
        else:
            print el, ' not found in xml file. Skipping...'
    tree.write(filename)
```

I don't understand what the above code is doing very well and I need to do the same on a json file. I open the file like below but can't go on from there. I understand that output/exp corresponds to the two layers in xml as in  but in json writing these output/exp line is different because i need to access it as I would access a dictionary and I don't know how to do that with 2 layers.

```py
def UpdateJSON(filename,config,silent=True,envartime=None):
    data=0
    with open(filename) as json_file:  
        data = json.load(json_file)
    data[config[0]]
```

Hopefully I explained it clearly. Thank you.

edit: here are json and xml files:

```
{
    "prints": {
        "frequency": "PT3H"
    }, 
    "logging": {
        "categories": "Info, Warning, Error, Fatal"
    }, 
    "initial": {
        "date": "2010-07-03T00:00:00Z", 
        "filename": "/home/algo/alpar/Desktop/temp/oops_run/exampleA8/fcst.restart.2010-07-03T00:00:00Z.PT0S"
    }, 
    "forecast_length": "P2D", 
    "output": {
        "date": "2010-07-03T00:00:00Z", 
        "datadir": "/home/algo/alpar/Desktop/temp/oops_run/exampleA8", 
        "frequency": "PT1H", 
        "type": "fc", 
        "exp": "fcst"
    }, 
    "model": {
        "jvalues_file": "/home/algo/alpar/Desktop/temp/oops_run/exampleA8/J_TUV_30m.txt", 
        "emissions_file": "/home/algo/alpar/Desktop/temp/oops_run/exampleA8/emissions.dat", 
        "advect_chemistry": 1, 
        "bottom_layer_depth": 4000, 
        "top_layer_depth": 6000, 
        "tstep": "PT10M"
    }, 
    "resolution": {
        "nx": 8, 
        "ny": 4, 
        "bc": 1
    }
}
```

```
<config>
   <prints>
      <frequency>PT3H</frequency>
   </prints>
   <logging>
      <categories>Info, Warning, Error, Fatal</categories>
   </logging>
   <initial>
      <date>2010-07-03T00:00:00Z</date>
      <filename>/home/algo/alpar/Desktop/temp/oops_run/example06/pert.restart.ens.1.2010-07-03T00:00:00Z.PT0S</filename>
   </initial>
   <forecast_length>P2D</forecast_length>
   <output>
      <date>2010-07-03T00:00:00Z</date>
      <datadir>/home/algo/alpar/Desktop/temp/oops_run/example06</datadir>
      <frequency>PT1H</frequency>
      <type>fc</type>
      <exp>freefcst</exp>
   </output>
   <model>
      <jvalues_file>/home/algo/alpar/Desktop/temp/oops_run/example06/J_TUV_30m.txt</jvalues_file>
      <emissions_file>/home/algo/alpar/Desktop/temp/oops_run/example06/emissions.dat</emissions_file>
      <advect_chemistry>1</advect_chemistry>
      <bottom_layer_depth>4000</bottom_layer_depth>
      <top_layer_depth>6000</top_layer_depth>
      <tstep>PT10M</tstep>
   </model>
   <resolution>
      <nx>8</nx>
      <ny>4</ny>
      <bc>1</bc>
   </resolution>
</config>
```

Comment: I guess config is your dictionary, config =  {'output/exp':'freefcst'} ? (yes, it is a dictionary)

Comment: Please edit your question to add the json and xml (or a sample of them if they're too long).

Comment: Once the json is loaded from disk it becomes a python `dict`. What do you want to modify in the dict?